# Issue with importing slidingmenu into an existing eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported the library into eclipse by going to File>Import>Existing android Code> etc
and now i have an extra project called "library" in my workspace

Then I right clicked on the project i want to implement this library to and clicked properties, added the library project, as shown in the screenshot below. But when I click Apply/Ok i get a jar dependency error, does anyone know how I can properly use the slidingmenu library in my app? Thanks

[image: Screenshot showing the imported library]

Comment: i guess android-suuport-v4.jar is there in both your project and library project. remove the duplicate  and give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jar mismatches are usually due to the support v4 library jar file being in both your project and the library. To fix this, make sure the entire project and its libraries has 1 copy of the jar by deleting any others. Afterwards, reference that one copy by right clicking your project and adding that copy as an external archive.

Comment: How would I remove the duplicate so I don't ruin the project? I just tried there and I ruined it. But I had a backup

Comment: What do you mean by ruin? For example, I am developing an app that uses the ActionBarSherlock library. That library already had a supportv4 .jar, so I deleted the one from my personal project libs. Then, I right-clicked my project and added the ABS supportv4 jar as an external archive to my project.

Comment: I mean ruin, as in, all sorts of errors come up. So I just delete the support.jar from the libs folder, then add it again through the "add external jar" button and add the other one from the library project?

Comment: Perfect! Everything works great now. For those of you who will use this as reference later, just delete the android support jar file in the libs folder, then right click the project, click android on the left hand side, then click add, then add the library project